# Angular2 with Semantic UI not working

Tags: node.js, angular, semantic-ui

I am using Angular2 with Nodejs. I have a list of employees each contains employee name, address, rank etc. I want to show information when user hovers mouse on the employee name. For that I am trying using semantic-ui with angular2 but I can't find any example other than (below link) which isn't descriptive.

https://github.com/vladotesanovic/ngSemantic

```
Nodejs:
npm install ng-semantic --save
npm install jquery --save

Index.html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css">

TestSemantic.ts
import {NgSemanticModule} from 'ng-semantic';

TestSemantic.html
<sm-button class="icon" sm-popup="Add users to your feed"><i class="add icon"></i></sm-button>
```

First it shows me 2 semantic errors which are:

node_modules/ng-semantic/ng-semantic/input/input.d.ts(2,29), error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.

node_modules/ng-semantic/ng-semantic/search/search.d.ts(2,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.

Only button is showing on TestSemantic.html but there is no pop-up displays

Comment: StackOverflow questions should contain the code that demonstrates what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. Code has added.

Comment: Do you have the forms module in your systemjs config?

Comment: No, I dont have systemjs file. I guess the existing project has Webpack.

Comment: I see. Don't know about webpack. Just ensure the module is listed as dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Note sure if this is still relevant, but did you install angular's forms module? ngSemantic depends on it as it extends form controls.

So check in package.json and node_modules if you have `@angular/forms`.

Based on the code in ngSemantic it should install @angular/forms automatically but it's worth checking.

Answer (score -1):

If you remove temporarily the `ngSemantic` import but instead use
`import @angular/forms` just to test that the import work at least for your code (apart for `ngSemantic`).

I note also that the error is in a d.ts file which is a typing definition file.

If you use webpack you should be able to recompile the bundled js from the dependencies inside `node_modules`

I am using `ngSemantic` with angular 2 with no problem.